# Открывается page-user.php, если эта страница не принадлежит этому пользователю

Tags: веб-программирование, php

Почему-то открывает page-user.php, если эта страница не принадлежит этому пользователю, что-то не так? (пользователь A открывает страницу пользователя B)

```
<?php
#Включаем сессии
session_start();
#Базовые переменные
$user = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$pageuser = $_GET['id'];
#Проверим, авторизирован ли пользователь

/* Если эта страница этого пользователя */ 
if ($pageuser != $user) {
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/incld/page-user.php');
    die();
}
/* Если эта страница не этого пользователя */
if ($_SESSION['authed'] == 'yes') {
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/incld/page-authed.php');

}
```

Comment: @Виталина ♦, не удаляйте, пожалуйста, мои комментарии.

Answer (score 1):

> $user = $_SESSION['user_name'];
>
> $pageuser = $_GET['id'];
>
> if ($pageuser !=
> $user) {..}

```
$pageuser != $user
```

Вы сравниваете идентификатор (id) c именем пользователя (user_name)

Comment: ID - это тоже имя пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

да думаю как всегда глупая ошибка какая нить) в любом случае странно что вы сравниваете, сравнив $_GET['id'] и $_SESSION['user_name'].

Comment: @Виталина ♦, не надо редактировать чужие мысли, хорошо? вам вроде только оформление можно трогать.

Comment: @Manitikyl самое главное что она вчера зарегалась и уже модератор

Comment: @misc, потому что (очевидно) этого пользователя пригласили сюда для того, чтобы сделать модератором. Не волнуйтесь, ничего киберстрашного не произошло, @Виталина ♦ наверняка вольется.